# How to apply Filter for Tree which is developed using QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

Implemented Tree using QStandardItemModel.. like below

```
QStandardItem *americaItem = new QStandardItem("America");
QStandardItem *mexicoItem =  new QStandardItem("Canada");
QStandardItem *usaItem =     new QStandardItem("USA");
QStandardItem *bostonItem =  new QStandardItem("Boston");
QStandardItem *europeItem =  new QStandardItem("Europe");
QStandardItem *italyItem =   new QStandardItem("Italy");
QStandardItem *romeItem =    new QStandardItem("Rome");
QStandardItem *veronaItem =  new QStandardItem("Verona");

//building up the hierarchy
rootNode->    appendRow(americaItem);
rootNode->    appendRow(europeItem);
americaItem-> appendRow(mexicoItem);
americaItem-> appendRow(usaItem);
usaItem->     appendRow(bostonItem);
europeItem->  appendRow(italyItem);
italyItem->   appendRow(romeItem);
italyItem->   appendRow(veronaItem);

//register the model
treeView->setModel(standardModel);
```

So now Im unable to do search operation, using that QFilterProxyModel im able to search only parent data.. Any suggestion to search parent and child rows too..(using filterAcceptsRow or any other)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented search filter like this:

1. Derived a class from `QSortFilterProxyModel`
2. Overrided the `filterAcceptsRow` method

```
bool FilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row,                                       const QModelIndex& source_parent) const
{
    // check the current item

    bool result = QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row,source_parent);

    QModelIndex currntIndex = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);

    if (sourceModel()->hasChildren(currntIndex))
    {
        // if it has sub items
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceModel()->rowCount(currntIndex) && !result; ++i)
        {
            // keep the parent if a children is shown
            result = result || filterAcceptsRow(i, currntIndex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

3. `mFilterProxyModel->setFilterRegExp(ui->mLeSearchFilter->text());`